# What does "p-q bijection" means?

Tags: calculus, functions

I know what 1-to-1 bijection means, nut I've found that annoying expression "Sometimes, one constructs a p — q bijection instead of a 1-1 bijection." And I truly don't understand what this supposed to mean!
 Any help? Please with examples if you can.
Here it is the paragraph:

"Counting by Bijection. Of two sets A, B, we know |B|, but |A| is unknown. 
If we succeed in constructing a bijection A <-> B, then |A| = |B|. A proof 
which shows |A| = |B|by such an explicit construction is called a bijective 
proof or combinatorial proof. Sometimes, one constructs a p — q bijection 
instead of a 1-1 bijection. "

That's it, very odd huh!

Comment: Give the context where you've encountered this expression...

Comment: a book: Problem solving strategies by Arthur Engel, chapter 5: Enumerative Combinatorics , page 87

Comment: For what it's worth, the phrase "1-1 bijection" is awful terminology. A bijection is, by definition, one-to-one.

Comment: Not everyone has that book available and at hand. Could you expand the quote above to maybe a full paragraph, so that we can see how Engel uses these bijections in practice?

Comment: Ok one moment please

Comment: Updated the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context, I'm guessing Engel means a counting trick whereby you have two sets $A,B$ and you assing $p$ elements of $B$ to each element of $A$, in such a way that each element of $B$ is assigned to $q$ elements of $A$. You can think of this as a bipartite graph between $A$ and $B$, where each vertex on the $A$ side has degree $p$ and each on the $B$ side has degree $q$. Then counting the edges in two different ways we get
$$p|A| = q|B|$$

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for helping

Comment: for future reference, if that completely resolves your question, you should accept the answer (so that it doesn't appear as unanswered)